# Can an F5 LTM leave a failed/flapping node offline

Tags: load-balancing, f5-big-ip

I have an F5 LTM load balancing a number of servers. If one of those servers fails and then recovers, can I have the LTM mark it down/in maintenance until I manually re-enable it?

The default behaviour of the LTM is to make the load balanced node available to the pool again if the healthcheck passes. If the server crashed for some reason and rebooted, it would be available for clients to connect to, and this is not what I would like to happen. I would like to be able to leave the pool member offline until I can work out what went wrong with the server.

Comment: I think the jargon term is “manual resume” in your health monitor but I don’t have an F5 to verify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bob is correct.   Specifically - open the PROPERTIES tab of your monitor.   Select ADVANCED options otherwise it will be hidden.   You should see ""Manual Resume" is now available - select Yes from the Yes/No checkbox.   What that does is make it so you have to go in and ENABLE it once again.